# Send link for approval and then save data

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am creating a simple MVC application where Secretary creates contact list for his boss.
Contact list has simple fields FirstName LastName Phone no.

**Catch**

Secretary cannot save contactList.

After submitting the contactList form , an email (containing link of contact) should go the boss and when Boss opens email he can approve or disapprove it.

When boss approves then only contact should be saved in Contact list

**Problem**
I am new to Asp.Net, i have Questions

1) when Secretary fills the contactList form and send to boss then where are the details saved ( i mean in which database??).

2) how to create am email link which after opening contains filled form + 2 new buttons **Approve** and **Disapprove**

**I have no code to post i mean i want to understand how to achieve that**

Comment: You can achieve that the way you want. Think of the design that would suit your needs then go and implement it. See what works and what does not work then ask your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your questions:

1. You would put the contacts in the database of your application, presumably in a table named `Contacts` and a status of `ApprovalPending`. After the boss approved the contact, its status could be changed to `Approved`.
2. You would create a view for the approval of a contact. That view could receive a parameter. This parameter would be the ID of the contact. The link in the email would simply point to that view and contain the ID as the query parameter.

If you have concrete questions about either of those, you should be posting new, concrete questions, ideally with code you have already tried.

Comment: To add a bit more: This system may need a login as well to check the role of the user attempting to approve. Otherwise anyone can approve using the query string. Obviously his question is just a starter.